# Fixing Gap in Knowledge about recursion: base conditions and state

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I have a gap in knowledge with recursion.  I understand the base case should terminate the recursion but I have difficulty choosing the correct one.

Moreover I have a problem in understanding how to manage states without updating the method signature.

Take for instance the problem of `largest adjacent element products`.  My understanding of divide and conquer is:

```
1) divide the problem into smaller problems:
    1.1) create a left array of the first two elements
    1.2) create a right array by removing the first element
2) conquer by recursion:
    2.1) repeat the function on the right array
    2.2) choose a good base case to terminate
3) combine the solution
    3.1) this is where things get tricky!? 
    3.2) for the task of multiplication, how do I persist the result
    after each recursion when each new call will re-instantiate the
    result list
```

A concrete example of this gap in knowledge is below:  The `base case` I chose is when the list has fewer than two elements, then return `0`.  Of course that works `except` when the product of two elements is `less than 0`.

Returning `None` for the base case is a problem with the state, because in `python3` None and `int` comparison throws an error.

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Complete code is below

```
def multiply(inputArray):
    m = inputArray[0] * inputArray[1]
    return m

def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray):
    # [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]
    if len(inputArray) <= 1:
        # return 0
        return None

    left = inputArray[:2]
    right = inputArray[1:]
    result = []

    result.append(adjacentElementsProduct(right))
    m = multiply(left)

    print(result, left, m)

    if len(result) == 0:
        result.append(m)
    else:
        if m >= result[0]:
            result.insert(0, m)

    return result[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem like you main problem is how to combine solutions. In every single iteration, what you need to combine is results of  left array and right array.

> how do I persist the result?

Just return max of left result and right result.

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray):
    # [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]
    if len(inputArray) <= 1:
        return None

    left = inputArray[:2]
    right = inputArray[1:]

    m = multiply(left)

    result = adjacentElementsProduct(right)

    # combine solutions
    if result is None:
        return m
    else:
        return max(m, result)
```

Testcases:

```
print(adjacentElementsProduct([3]))
None
print(adjacentElementsProduct([3,6]))
18
print(adjacentElementsProduct([3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]))
21
```

Comment: `python` has no append left.  there's an `insert(0, m)`.  Also the solution should return a single integer.

Comment: @SamHammamy fixex it. And what should be the exact result? I don't understand `adjacent element products`.

Comment: The output should be `21`: the largest element product

Comment: @SamHammamy So what you want is **largest** adjacent element product. You didn't mention that.

Comment: you are still returning a list, not an integer.  My apologies for the down vote, I correct and up voted but I can't accept as correct answer because it's still returning a list

Comment: @SamHammamy Now it's perfect.